# In Google Directory API, how do I add a user using javascript?

Tags: javascript, http-post, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I have the Google Directory API [Javascript quickstart](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/js) working.  This part of the code lists the first 10 users in the directory:

```js
      gapi.client.directory.users.list({
        'customer': 'my_customer',
        'maxResults': 10,
        'orderBy': 'email'
      }).then(function(response) {
        var users = response.result.users;
        appendPre('Users:');

        appendPre('test')

        if (users && users.length > 0) {
          for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            var user = users[i];
            appendPre('-' + user.primaryEmail + ' (' + user.name.fullName + ')');
          }
        } else {
          appendPre('No users found.');
        }
      });
```

I want to add a user to the directory.  It looks like this is done using [users: insert](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/insert).  So after removing the 'readonly' part from the scope, I replace the above code snippet with this:

```js
var user = {
        "password": "Testpass123",
        "primaryEmail": "albert.smith@mydomain.com",
        "name": {
          "givenName": "albert",
          "familyName": "smith"
        }
      };
      
gapi.client.directory.users.insert(user);
```

Obviously this does not work, but I am unsure what I am missing.  There is a "Try this API" tool on the users:insert reference page, and when I plug in the properties of 'user' in the "request body" field, it adds the user.

I'm not sure how to make a request body though, and I can't find a solution in the docs.  The users:list method does not need a request body.  I tried something like this, which also didn't work:

```js
gapi.client.request({
         'path': 'https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users',
         'method': 'POST',
         'body': user
       });
```

Hoping someone can give me at least a general idea of what to do.  I'm pretty new at this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this dummy data derived from [Apps Script's Admin SDK  Add user](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory#add_user) and replace with your correct details:

sample request body:

```
var user = {
    primaryEmail: 'liz@example.com',
    name: {
      givenName: 'Elizabeth',
      familyName: 'Smith'
    },
    // Generate a random password string.
    password: Math.random().toString(36)
  };
```

Comment: That looks similar enough to my request body, I'm sure either would work.

My problem is that I don't know what to do with this 'user' variable.  I tried `gapi.client.directory.users.insert(user);` but that did not work.

In other words: how do I insert a request body into the user.insert function?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the user object in a resource object like:

```
var user = {
  resource: {
   "password": "Testpass123",
   "primaryEmail": "albert.smith@mydomain.com",
   "name": {
      "givenName": "albert",
      "familyName": "smith"
    }
  }
}
```

I can't find a reference for this anymore so maybe someone else can post but it is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/insert :

```
function execute() {
            return gapi.client.directory.users.insert({
                "resource": {
                "name": {
                "familyName": "Shmoger",
                "givenName": "Joey"
                },
                "password": "ShmoeyJoey!",
                "primaryEmail": "shmogerjoe@grower.com"
            }
            })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
        }
```